# Sending a DTO in a post request

Tags: java, postman, dto

The following code adds a data set to my database via a post.
The table has a foreign key called customer that is represented by a DTO. 
I am using post man to send the post however I am not sure how to input a dto into post man. Do you all know how to?

Comment: have you tried request body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of @RequestParam, use @RequestBody:

```
@RequestBody CustomerDTO customer
```

edit: what you should pass in the body:

```
{ "id": 13, "name": "Steve", "nmcAcctNo": 13165464, "hubId": 235445, "createTime": 1536382800000, "updateTime": 1536382800000 }
```

Comment: I did that however when I put this in the body it tells me format not supported.

Comment: "customer": {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "Steve",
        "nmcAcctNo": 13165464,
        "hubId": 235445,
        "createTime": 1536382800000,
        "updateTime": 1536382800000
    }

Comment: remove `"customer":`

Comment: I removed customer and still got the same problem. Do i need to make the other two arguments body as well?

Comment: no, the other 2 arguments are query param: `http://blabla.com/addUnit/?ua=123&vehicleId=123`, by default they are mandatory. What is exactly your error?

Comment: That's how i have it and i am getting this error still when i hit send. The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

Comment: I had it on text. Thank you so much!